# Reed and Simon, Fourier Analysis and Self-Adjointness, second corollary to Theorem X.$25$: how to show that $D(A^2)$ is dense in $D(A)$ for its norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators, unbounded-operators

This question arose while trying to figure out the proof of the second corollary to Theorem X.$25$ in Reed and Simon's *Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness*, stated as follows:

> Theorem X.$25$: Let $A : D(A) \subset H \to H$, $H$ Hilbert space, be a closed densely defined operator. Then $A^* \circ A$ is self-adjoint.
>
> Corollary: Let $A$ be a closed operator. Then any core for $A$ is a form core for $A^* \circ A$.
>
> Corollary: If $A$ is symmetric and $A^2$ is densely defined, then $A^* \circ A$ is the Friedrichs extension of $A^2$.

I had no major problem with the proof of the Theorem itself nor with the first corollary.

By the proof of Theorem X.$25$, I did recognise that $D(A)$ is the form domain of $A^* \circ A$ with the complete norm below:
$$\| \cdot \|_A : \varphi \mapsto \sqrt{\|A(\varphi)\|^2 + \|\varphi\|^2}$$
(which coincides with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{+1}$, used for a form domain of a positive form, in this particular case) hence if $B$ denotes the Friedrichs extension of $A^2$, then if we do have $B = A^* \circ A$, the form domain $Q(B)$ of $B$ needs to be $D(A)$ too.
On the other hand, the form domain of $B$ is the completion of $D(A^2)$ for $\|\cdot\|_{+1} = \|\cdot\|_A$, hence it is equal to the $\|\cdot\|_A$-closure of $D(A^2)$ in $D(A)$.
Lastly, it is easy to see that $A^* \circ A$ does extend $A^2$ as $A^*$ extends $A$, and the domain of $A^* \circ A$ is contained in $D(A)$, yet the Friedrichs extension $B$ of $A^2$ is the only self-adjoint extension whose domain is contained in the form domain of $B$, therefore if we can show that $Q(B) = D(A)$ then we'll have $B = A^* \circ A$ with no issue.

**My question today is thus**:

> How does one show that $D(A^2)$ is $\|\cdot\|_A$-dense in $D(A)$? Alternatively, if that claim is not actually true, what did I misunderstand?

**What I've tried**: Since $D(A)$ is a Hilbert space for $\|\cdot\|_A$, I've tried looking at $Q(B)^{\perp_A} = D(A^2)^{\perp_A}$, where $\perp_A$ means the orthogonal for $\|\cdot\|_A$ in contrast with $\perp$ which I'll use for the usual orthogonal in $H$. Assume the same about other notations involving $A$.
We can see that $D(A^2)^{\perp_A} = \operatorname{Ran}\left(A^2 + \operatorname{Id}\right)^\perp \cap D(A)$ thanks to the following relation for all $\varphi \in D(A^2)$ and $\psi \in D(A)$:
$$\langle \varphi, \psi\rangle_A = \langle A(\varphi), A(\psi)\rangle + \langle \varphi, \psi\rangle = \left\langle A^2(\varphi) + \varphi, \psi\right\rangle$$
Now, we have $\overline{\operatorname{Ran}\left(A^2 + \operatorname{Id}\right)} = \operatorname{Ker}\left((A^2)^* + \operatorname{Id}\right)^\perp$ due to usual properties of adjoints, hence: $$D(A^2)^{\perp_A} = \operatorname{Ker}\left((A^2)^* + \operatorname{Id}\right) \cap D(A)$$
Take $\psi$ in the above space. What I would like to do is the following manipulation, with an exclamation point where the outlier equality lies:
$$0 = \langle (A^2)^*(\psi) + \psi, \psi\rangle \overset{!}{=} \langle A(\psi), A(\psi) \rangle + \langle \psi, \psi\rangle = \|\psi\|^2_A$$
which would tell me that $\psi = 0$, and thus would let me conclude that, $D(A)$ being complete, $Q(B)$ is indeed the whole of $D(A)$.
However I don't really know how to proceed directly since it's not clear to me that we should have $\psi \in D\left((A^*)^2\right)$ in order to be able to write $(A^2)^*(\psi) = (A^*)^2(\psi)$ which would justify that equality, so I tried taking out a sequence in $D(A^2)$ converging to $\psi$ in $H$.

Consider $(\psi_n)_n \subset D(A^2)$ converging to $\psi$ for $\|\cdot\|_H$. This sequence exists by denseness of $D(A^2)$ in $H$.
We obtain:
$$0 = \langle (A^2)^*(\psi) + \psi, \psi_n\rangle = \left\langle \psi, A^2(\psi_n) \right\rangle + \langle \psi, \psi_n\rangle = \langle A(\psi), A(\psi_n) \rangle + \langle \psi, \psi_n\rangle = \langle \psi, \psi_n\rangle_A$$
It's almost what I need yet I don't see how to go forward from there as the function $\langle \psi, \cdot\rangle_A$ might not be $\|\cdot\|_H$-continuous.

Feel free to edit and/or re-tag if necessary or appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
$$

It is a second attempt.

**Friedrichs extension**

Let $S$ is symmetric operator with positive lower bound.  Consider
$$
  H_s = \overline{\left\{ (Sf, g): f, g\in H, f,g\in D(S) \right\}},
$$
and $\psi: x \mapsto x: H_s\to H$ is continuous one-to-one (see citation below) with dense image (trivial),
$\psi^t$ (continuous adjoint) is also one-to-one with dense image.
$$
  (f, x)_H = (\psi f, x)_H = (f, \psi^tx)_s, f\in H_s, x\in H
$$
In particular, for $f\in D(S),$ $(f, x)_H = (Sf, \psi^tx)_H.$

Let $g\in \im \psi^t = D((\psi^t)^{-1}) \subset H_s,$
then
$$
  (f, (\psi^t)^{-1}g)_H = (Sf, g)_H, f\in D(S)
$$

It shows that $g\in D(S^*)$ and $(\psi^t)^{-1}g = S^*g,$ i.e.  $(\psi^t)^{-1} = D(S^*)|H_s$ is
Friedrichs extension of $S.$

**One-to-one (Weidmann "Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces")**
If $S$ is semi-bounded symmetric operator with lower bound $\gamma > 0$ then $s(f, g) = (Sf,
  g)_H, f,g\in D(S)$ defines a semi-bounded sesquilinear form $s$ on $D(S).$ Then $H_s\to H$ is
one-to-one.
Take $f_n$ $\left\| \cdot \right\|_s$-Cauchy sequence such that $f_n\to 0$ in $H:$
$$
    \begin{split}
      \left\| f_n \right\|^2_s \le
      \left| (f_n, f_n-f_m)_s  + (f_n, f_m)_s\right| \le\\
      \left\| f_n \right\|_s \left\| (f_n-f_m) \right\|_s +
      \left\| S f_n \right\| \left\| f_m \right\|
    \end{split}
  $$
Make first summand small by $\left\| \cdot \right\|_s$-Cauchy and second by $f_n\to0.$

**Conclusion**
$$
H(A^2)\xrightarrow{i} H(A^*\circ A)\xrightarrow{\Psi:x \mapsto x} H.
$$
are continuous for norms $(A^2\varphi, \varphi) + (\varphi, \varphi), \varphi\in D(A^2)$ and
$(A^*A\varphi', \varphi') + (\varphi', \varphi'), \varphi'\in D(A^*\circ A),$ where $i$ is an
isometry and $i^t$ is orthogonal projection on $H(A^2)$ in $H(A^* \circ A).$

Friedrichs extensions are:
\begin{align}
  F(I+A^2) &= ((\Psi \circ i)^t)^{-1} &\subseteq& 1+(A^2)^* \\
  F(I+A^* \circ A) &= (\Psi^t)^{-1} &\subseteq& 1+(A^* \circ A)^*
\end{align}
$D(F(I+A^2)) \subseteq H(A^2)$ and $D(F(I+A^* \circ A)) \subseteq H(A^* \circ A).$

$$
  (\Psi \circ i)^t = i^t \circ \Psi^t,
$$
If $\im \Psi^t \cap \ker i^t \neq 0$ then there would be no one-to-one $F(I + A^2),$
so $\im \Psi^t \subseteq \im i$ and $i^t \circ \Psi^t = \Psi^t.$
That is $F(I + A^2) = F(I + A^* \circ A).$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Before I accept, I just want to make sure I understand one point: would you mind to elaborate a bit on why $(S + I )\circ i$ has dense range? I'm not quite sure of how one can arrive to this conclusion, though I'm sure it's probably fairly simple and I'm just not getting it right now. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: I think, it is due to closed $A^2.$ That is because  $i^*\circ (I +S^*)$ has trivial kernel.